# moongodb push only creating new_id in database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I tried to update and push the Lowongan array,
 but every time I made  a patch request only new_id was created in DB,
 There's no error in    the console only shows the successfully saved data but in DB it's only  keys _id

I have tried changing the data request, and look for the schema type

[image]>

*Please I need help*

```
//subschema

company_postSchema = new Schema({
  job_post_title: { type: String, required: true },
  number_of_vacancy: { type: Number, required: true },
  commitment_type: { type: String, required: true },
  salary: { type: String, required: true },
  location: { type: String, required: true },
  remote_job: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  visa: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  forreignn_applicant: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  visa_sponsorship: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  job_description: { type: String, required: true },
});

//parent schema

const employerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    account_type: { type: String },
    company_name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    phone_number: { type: String, required: true },
    company_website: { type: String, required: true },
    company_country: {
      label: { type: String, required: true },
      value: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    company_city: { type: String, required: true },
    company_address: { type: String, required: true },
    company_logo: { type: String },
    lowongan: [{ company_postSchema }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);



//new post lowongan request
{
    "job_post_title":"dsadas" ,
    "number_of_vacancy": 2,
    "commitment_type":"dasdasd",
    "salary": "20000",
    "location": "jakarta",
    "remote_job": true,
    "visa": true,
    "forreignn_applicant": false,
    "visa_sponsorship": false,
    "job_description": "dadadasdadsadadad"
}

//API request handle 

export default async function company_acc(req, res) {
  let connect = await connectToDB(); //connect DB are ok
  if (req.method === "PATCH") {
    let data = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    let user = "64fc1bf744978576f35a9d72";
    try {
      let cari = await employer.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: user },
        {
          $push: { lowongan: { data } },
        }
      );
      await cari.save();
      res.json(cari);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({ err: error.message });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `findOneAndUpdate` _**and**_ `.save()`?  You may want to use `returnOriginal: false` in the `findOneAndUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Mongoose docs about **subSchema**, 
 It seems, I applied it wrong in my `employer_postSchema`. It should have been: `[{{{data}}]`

**So, I changed it to be:**

```
employerpostschema : [subchema]
```

**Also, I changed this code in the API handler:**

```
let cari = await employer.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: user },
        {
          $push: { lowongan: data }, // data without curly bracket
        }
```